# Connection is not defined

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

I have the following code

```
    <?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "hawkI";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

$userExist = false;
$userIP = null;
$userHasFinish = null;
$userLastPage = null;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

function getIPforBDD(){
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

function UpdateUserProfile()
{
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip = ".getIPforBDD();
    $result = $dbh->query($requete);

    if($resultat->rowCount() == 0)
        exit();

    foreach($result as $ligne)
    {       
        $userIP = $ligne['ip'];
        $userhasFinish = $ligne['finish'];
        $userLastPage = $ligne['lastPage'];
    }
}

function CheckUserPosition()
{
    UpdateUserProfile();
    if(!$userExist)
        AddUser();

    return GetUserStatus();
}

function GetUserStatus()
{
    $page;
    if($userHasFinish)
        $page = "end.php";
    else
        $page = $userLastPage;

    return $page;
}

function AddUser()
{
    $requete = "INSERT INTO users (ip, finish, lastPage) VALUES (".getIPforBDD().", ".false.", questionnaire_initial.php)";
    $result = $dbh->query($requete);
}

function SavePageInBDD($page){
    $requete = "UPDATE users SET lastPage = '.$page.' WHERE ip = ".getIPforBDD();
    $result = $dbh->query($requete);
} 
?>
```

But, I have a problem when I use it

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\wamp64\www\HawkI\bdd.php
>   on line 66

I do not understand correctly how PHP work it's the first time I use it, but I tried to make

```
global $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $password);
```

That doesn't work too.

Also, it seems that value that are put outside of functions are not global like it would be in js, how can I make something accessible from everywhere (like file that include that file)

Thanks

Comment: construct it as a class, and add the credentials in the construtor, set the properties and such, or just simply inject the connection object in the arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way would be to do something like this:

```
function getDB(){
  $dbh = null;
  try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $password);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
   return $dbh;
}
```

And than in your functions do this:

```
function AddUser()
{
    $dbh = getDB();
    if(!is_null($dbh)){
         $requete = "INSERT INTO users (ip, finish, lastPage) VALUES (".getIPforBDD().", ".false.", questionnaire_initial.php)";
         $result = $dbh->query($requete);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is OK, but it creates a new connection when you try go getDB. Why not using global keyword of  $bdh inside function scope?

Answer (score 0):

To use `$dbh` inside a function, you need to include `global` keyword inside the function scope.

You can find the global keyword explanation here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global

```
function AddUser()
{
    global $dbh;
    $requete = "INSERT INTO users (ip, finish, lastPage) VALUES (".getIPforBDD().", ".false.", questionnaire_initial.php)";
    $result = $dbh->query($requete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "hawkI";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$userExist = false;
$userIP = null;
$userHasFinish = null;
$userLastPage = null;
$dbh = NULL;
function db () {
    try {   
        if ($GLOBALS['dbh']===NULL){ 
            $GLOBALS['dbh'] = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $password);
        }
        return $GLOBALS['dbh'];    
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function SavePageInBDD($page){
    $dbh = db();       
    $requete = "UPDATE users SET lastPage = '.$page.' WHERE ip = ".getIPforBDD();
    $result = $dbh->query($requete);
}
```